# Django: How to get a time difference from the time post?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

Say I have a class in model

```
 class Post(models.Model):
     time_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

     def get_time_diff(self):
         timediff = timediff = datetime.datetime.now() - self.time_posted
         print timediff # this line is never executed
         return timediff
```

I defined a get_time_diff to get the time difference from the time when the Post is posted up to now, according to the document, the DateTimeField should be able to be converted to datetime automatically, is that correct? Why the print statement is never being run? How can you extract the time difference?

Beside, if you get a time difference, is there an easy way to convert the time difference to an integer, like the number of seconds of the total time.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your code is already working; a [`datetime.timedelta` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) is returned.

To get the total number of *seconds* instead, you need to call the [`.total_seconds()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) on the resulting `timedelta`:

```
from django.utils.timezone import utc

def get_time_diff(self):
    if self.time_posted:
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
        timediff = now - self.time_posted
        return timediff.total_seconds()
```

`.total_seconds()` returns a `float` value, including microseconds.

Note that you need to use a *timezone aware* `datetime` object, since the Django `DateTimeField` handles timezone aware `datetime` objects as well. See [Django Timezones documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zones).

Demonstration of `.total_seconds()` (with naive `datetime` objects, but the principles are the same):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> time_posted = datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 31, 12, 55, 10)
>>> timediff = datetime.datetime.now() - time_posted
>>> timediff.total_seconds()
1304529.299168
```

Because both objects are timezone aware (have a `.tzinfo` attribute that is not `None`), calculations between them take care of timezones and subtracting one from the other will do the right thing when it comes to taking into account the timezones of either object.

Comment: Thanks first but in my case the time_posted is a DateTimeField. I tried, it does not work.

Comment: @dorafmon: in your custom model method `self.time_posted` returns a `datetime` instance, see [Model Methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#model-methods).

Comment: @dorafmon ...although the `blank=True` suggests you might not get a valid `datetime` back, so you may have to check its validity before doing the subtraction.

Comment: @Aya: Interesting, mussed the `blank=True` there. Added an `if` statement, now `get_time_diff` will return `None` if `self.time_posted` is not defined.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but how can you convert the DatetimeField into a datetime? I got confused here actually.

Comment: @dorafmon: It has *already* been converted. See the documentation I linked you to; the example there uses a `DateField` instead but the principle is the same.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, I might be a little dump here, but since a DataTimeField can be converted to datatime automatically, why I cannot simply do ```datetime.datetime.now()-self.time_posted```.

Comment: @dorafmon: How are you calling the `.get_time_diff()` method? What error do you see when you call it? You need to tell us more about what problems you are experiencing. When you have a `Post` *result* object, calling `.get_time_diff()` Just Works.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There is no error message, but using the code in the question up there. the print function is never executed, Also this function does not returen anything at all.

Comment: @dorafmon: clearly you are not calling the code you think you are calling; there either will be a return value (at the very least `None`) or there will be an exception.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28256/discussion-between-dorafmon-and-martijn-pieters)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I had to add a line to the answer, since I still needed to read through your full chat to understand my error.

Comment: @aorcsik: `utcnow()` is not timezone aware either, but relies on your OS instead to tell it what the current UTC time is. The OS is timezone aware, but the resulting `datetime.datetime` object is *not*.

Comment: @aorcsik: As such, I had to roll back your edit as it was incorrect. Only attaching a timezone object to a `datetime.datetime` object makes it timezone-aware.

Comment: @MartijnPieters right, right... just figured, sry. I get the time zone from the datetime from the database and set it to the now datetime, is that correct?

Comment: @aorcsik: it is the `.replace(tzinfo=utc)` method call that returns a new `datetime.datetime()` instance with a timezone object attached; that is the timezone-aware object.

Comment: @aorcsik: No, just stick to UTC; because both the `now` object and `self.time_posted` are fully timezone aware, the result is always going to be accurate. The `datetime.datetime()` objects take care of handling the timezone details for you.

Comment: @aorcsik: By sticking to UTC you save yourself all those headaches.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, thank you very much! Could you please add these to the answer, maybe it will make others life easier next time :)

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you are doing this within a template, you can also use the [timesince](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince) template tag.

For example:

```
{{ blog_date|timesince:comment_date }}
```

Comment: Best Answer Thank you

Comment: Thanks! Any idea of how to get the resulting duration in seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
timediff = datetime.datetime.now() - self.pub_date
```

should work to get the time difference. However, this returns [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object. To get difference in seconds you use `.seconds` attribute

```
timediff = datetime.datetime.now() - self.pub_date
timediff.seconds  # difference in seconds.
```

Comment: I don't think that will work if the difference is more than one day.

Comment: @Aya, I think it will. Do you know why it won't?

Comment: Well, [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) say that the `seconds` attribute is "Between 0 and 86399 inclusive".

Comment: @Rohan: There is a separate `.days` attribute. `.seconds` only contains the remainder; an event 10 days and 534 seconds age has a `.seconds` attribute with `534`, and it's `.days` attribute will be `10`. Use `.total_seconds()` to turn that into a seconds-only value.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to put this process in you Django signals. Here's the one that is working for me. Hope this helps!

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import YourModel
from datetime import datetime

@receiver(pre_save, sender = YourModel)
def beforeSave(sender, instance, **kwargs): 
     date_format = "%H:%M:%S"

     # Getting the instances in your model.
     time_start = str(instance.time_start)
     time_end = str(instance.time_end)

     # Now to get the time difference.
     diff = datetime.strptime(time_end, date_format) - datetime.strptime(time_start, date_format)

     # Get the time in hours i.e. 9.60, 8.5
     result = diff.seconds / 3600;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply we can add the custom property to calculate the time difference with the help `@property` decorator in that model.

```py
from django.utils import timezone


class Post(models.Model):
    time_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField()

    @property
    def time_diff(self):
        return timezone.now() - self.time_posted
```

`time_diff` will return object of `datetime.timedelta`

---

```py
post = Post.objects.get(pk=1) # Post model object

# time diff in seconds.
post.time_diff.seconds
>>> 652
# time diff in days.
post.time_diff.days
>>> 0
```

*Already answered above nicely by Martijn Pieters, just adding `@property`, and `django.utils.timezone` to calculate the difference with respective timezone from `settings.py`*